# Reducible and irreducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Im stuck on something..
Why is $f(x)=2x$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

I know that $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}(x)$, the point of my question is:

> Why are invertible elements not taken into consideration while decomposing something?

Comment: What is your exact definition of irreducibility over a non-field like $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: F(x) =g(x) h(x) such that g(x) and h(x) both are not invertible. I'm not understanding why they came up with this rule, to prevent what exactly? What do invertible elements change?

Comment: This might be helpful in understanding why we care about the distinction between irreducible and prime elements, and why they are defined the way they are: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109014/prime-elements-irreducible-elements-unique-factorization-rings

Comment: Also, by your definition, $2x$ is reducible: $2x = 2 \cdot x$, neither factors are units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, whereas $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

Any invertible element divides every element; if invertible elements “counted”, then nothing would be irreducible, and then notion becomes worthless. It would be as if, in the integers, we said that $p$ is prime if and only if it cannot be written as $p=ab$. If we used that definition, then no element would be prime, because we would always be able to write any integer $p$ as $p=1\times p$.

Similarly, if $u$ is invertible in a domain, then there exists $v$ such that $uv=1$. Then any element $f$ could be written as $f=u(vf)$, so nothing would be irreducible.